# KXRORS S300 PCIe x16 riser cable size?

Tags: pc, pcie, case

I wonder if anyone knows what's the size of the PCIe 3.0 Riser cable included with the case?
I bought this case and turns out, my Motherboard and GPU are PCIe 4.0.  I'm thinking about buying a PCIe 4.0 Riser cable for replacing the default one, but I want to be sure which one.

[image]

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J-6W5hCCgpg

I saw a few reviews from amazon that says these sizes will work:

- 185mm (dual-reverse)
- 190mm  (dual-reverse)
- 250mm (straight)

In this video (S300 build), their using a RTX 4070, and a PCIe 4.0 cable to replace the 3.0 one.

[image]

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WLlzceFJwe4

Which one would you buy?